# Unsupported Media Type while hitting my JAVA api through Postman

Tags: java, rest, controller, postman

I am a beginner in REST-api development and I am facing this error : "Unsupported Media Type" while hitting my java api through postman. My Pojo Class is :

```
public class OrderRequest implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public OrderRequest() {}

private long orderNo;
private int rateOverallExperience;
private String apiName;
private Double apiVersion;

public long getOrderNo() {
    return orderNo;
}
public int getRateOverallExperience() {
    return rateOverallExperience;
}
public String getApiName() {
    return apiName;
}
public Double getApiVersion() {
    return apiVersion;
}

public void setOrderNo(long orderNo) {
    this.orderNo = orderNo;
}
public void setRateOverallExperience(int rateOverallExperience) {
    this.rateOverallExperience = rateOverallExperience;
}
public void setApiName(String apiName) {
    this.apiName = apiName;
}
public void setApiVersion(Double apiVersion) {
    this.apiVersion = apiVersion;
}
}
```

My controller class for this is :

```
@RestController
public class OrderRatingController {

public OrderRatingController() {}

@Autowired
private OrderRequestService ordRequestService;

@Autowired
private ProductRatingService prdRatingService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrderRatings", method = RequestMethod.POST
            ,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)                   //"application/json"
public OrderRequest saveOrder(@RequestBody OrderRequest requestObj) {

    System.out.println("Inside saveOrder. Json Object recieved : " + requestObj);

//...OTHER CODE...
    return requestObj;
}
}
```

I am using Jetty server(version:9.4.0.M0) to test my api.

In `Postman>Body tab>raw` , I have selected `JSON(application/json)` and sending :

> {
>   "orderNo" : "737521F547D00D26",
>   "rateOverallExperience" : 4,
>   "apiName": "giveitemrating", 
>   "apiVersion":"1.0"
>   }

Postman Header related details in a pic/snap:

[image: Postman Header related details in a pic/snap]

When I am sending this, I get an `Unsupported Media Type` error. Anyone has any idea about this?

**EDIT** : As suggested in the comments, Updated controller class a follows : `@RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrderRatings", method = RequestMethod.POST
                ,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, headers = "Accept=application/json")`

Further added a header in POSTMAN gui : `Accept` with value `application/json` .

This is how postman request looks like after sending the request(still showing the error but change in resultant headers) :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcDb3.png)

Comment: Try adding an `accept` header to your request (value `application/json`). Youy may also want to add `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`  to your `@RequestMapping` .

Comment: headers = "Accept=application/json"   add this line in request mapping and try

Comment: @Arnaud sir, Thank you for your immediate response. I have updated ```@RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrderRatings", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)```  and two headers ```Content-Type``` and ```accept``` with value ```application/json``` in Postman UI. Is this what you suggested? It is still showing same error with headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to configure the consumes or produces attribute at all. Spring will automatically serve JSON based on the following factors.

1. The accepts header of the request is application/json
2. @ResponseBody annotated method
3. Jackson library on classpath
4. You can use the @RestController instead of @Controller annotation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated ```@RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrderRatings", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")```
 and two headers ```Content-Type``` and ```Accept``` with value ```application/json``` in Postman UI. It is still showing me same error of ```Unsupported Media Type``` .    ALSO on sending request, it is showing ```Accept →application/octet-stream, text/plain, application/xml, text/xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/*+xml, multipart/form-data, */*``` and ```Content-Length →0``` . Will much appreciate your response. Tx

Comment: Are you change it @Responsebody and try it.The spring not returned pojo class.You return pojo class use jackson libraray